# Como incluir um jar ao executar um arquivo Java por linha de comando

Tags: java, jar

Toda vez que executo o programa preciso chamar uma biblioteca especifica, que no caso é `/home/usuario/Programas/weka-x-x-x/weka.jar`, porém toda vez que executo o programa, tenho que incluir o seguinte comando `java -cp /home/usuario/Programas/weka-x-x-x/weka.jar` para que as bibliotecas sejam executadas.

Gostaria de saber como faço para que essa biblioteca esteja inclusa por padrão no CLASSPATH, encontrei este comando no Stack Overflow:

`export CLASSPATH="dir1;dir2;path/to/jar/containing/AnotherClass;...` porém o mesmo não funcionou.

Comment: Você tá fazendo uso de alguma IDE?

Comment: Não, uso linha de comando.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Definir bibliotecas sem alterar o Java

Não é recomendável definir um `classpath` global. Pode causar efeitos colaterais indesejados em outros programas.

Para evitar repetição, crie um arquivo *shell script* contendo os comando que você precisa, use o `chmod` para definir permissões de execução para o arquivo e use o novo "executável" ao invés de chamar o Java diretamente quando precisar.

## Usando a variável `CLASSPATH`

Se ainda assim quiser definir um `classpath` global, o correto é usando a variável de ambiente `CLASSPATH`. Porém, troque o ponto-e-vírgula por dois-pontos na separação de diretórios, como a seguir:

```
export CLASSPATH="dir1:dir2:path/to/jar/containing/AnotherClass:...
```

O ponto-e-vírgula é usado em ambientes Windows enquanto os dois-pontos é usado em ambientes Unix/Linux.

Além disso, se quiser que a variável de ambiente esteja presente em todas as sessões do linux, mesmo após a reinicialização do sistema, você vai precisar adicionar o comando `export` em algum script de inicialização.

## Alterando a instalação do Java

Como observado [nesta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10488363/1683070), você pode colocar o jar na pasta `ext` da instalação do Java:

```
JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext
```

Mais uma vez, não aconselho fazer isso. Mesmo bibliotecas muito comuns às vezes podem gerar conflitos. Por exemplo, algum projeto mais antigo pode depender de uma versão mais antiga do mesmo jar usado por uma aplicação mais nova.

Comment: Mas não tenho como incluir essa biblioteca como padrão no Java para simplesmente não precisar mais me referenciar a ela? Faço algo parecido no NetBeans, apenas incluindo na biblioteca padrão o arquivo jar.

Comment: @pmargreff NetBeans é um editor, ele simplesmente vai adicionar automaticamente a biblioteca no `classpath` em cada execução. Não considero correto adicionar nenhuma biblioteca diretamente na instalação do Java, pois pode causar efeitos colaterais em outros programas, mas vou atualizar a resposta em como você pode fazer isso.

Comment: Ok, irei considerar sua sugestão, obrigado pela resposta.